# Trying to send json array to my json server with curl

Tags: json, haskell, curl

I need to identify what `JSON` values my server expects. I've been doing testing within Haskell, and all is well. So now I need to take the next step so I can document what these values look like for other people to use.

One of my `REST` methods expects an Array

`Array (fromList [String "BNAP",Number 312])`
is how Haskell expresses this.

Testing with `cURL`, I want to do something like this:

```
curl -D- -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '["BNAP":312]'      
http://10.64.16.6:3000/Read
```

But this seems to not be valid `JSON`

`ParseError {errorContexts = ["]"], errorMessage = "Failed reading: satisfyWith", errorPosition = 1:8}`

If Haskell was expecting an Object `Object  (fromList [String "BNAP",Number 312])` for example, the JSON would be expressed this way
`--data '{"BNAP":312}'`

So to me, it follows that my above attempt would be right. But, it's not. So, how does one express an Array with one Pair consisting of a String and a Number, with cURL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colon is not valid JSON here:

```
["BNAP":312]
       ^
```

Array elements should be separated by a comma:

```
["BNAP", 312]
```

If you wanted an array with a single key-value pair, you need to add curly braces:

```
[{"BNAP": 312}]
```